# onCreate() method of GridView is never called

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I have a gridView as seen here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_drag_and_drop_app"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#00FF00">

            <!-- Editext for Search -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/Search_applications"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvApps"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
 />
    </LinearLayout>
 </SlidingDrawer>

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLinkToPersonalize"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/Personalize"
        android:textColor="#21dbd4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<GridView 
android:id="@+id/GRIDVIEW1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="60dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
 >  

</GridView>

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/trash_can"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/trashcanDescription_Delete"
    android:padding="40dip"
    android:src="@drawable/trashcan"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then have my adapter for my gridView in a seperate class as seen here:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;
IMPORTS
public class GridView extends Activity { // implements OnItemLongClickListener, OnDragListener{

ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private BaseAdapter adapter;
private int draggedIndex = -1;
android.widget.GridView gridView = (android.widget.GridView) findViewById(R.id.GRIDVIEW1);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop_app);
    Log.d("GridView", "onCreate called");
    drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern1);
    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern2);
    // gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter = new BaseAdapter() {

        @Override
        // Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in
        // the data set.
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup gridView) {
            // try to reuse the views.
            ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
            // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse
            // it
            if (view == null) {
                view = new ImageView(GridView.this);
            }
            /*Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

            Bitmap default_b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

            view.setImageBitmap(default_b);*/
            view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
            view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
            view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        // Get the row id associated with the specified position in the
        // list.
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        // Get the data item associated with the specified position in the
        // data set.
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return drawables.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        // How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.
        public int getCount() {
            return drawables.size();
        }
    });
}

/*@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> gridView, View view,
        int position, long row) {
    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((String) view.getTag());
    ClipData clipData = new ClipData((CharSequence) view.getTag(),
            new String[] { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN }, item);
    view.startDrag(clipData, new View.DragShadowBuilder(view), null, 0);
    View trashCan = findViewById(R.id.trash_can);
    trashCan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    trashCan.setOnDragListener(GridView.this);
    trashCan.setOnDragListener(GridView.this);
    draggedIndex = position;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
    switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // Drag has started
        // If called for trash resize the view and return true
        if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
            view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
            view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
            return true;
        } else // else check the mime type and set the view visibility
        if (dragEvent.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(
                ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        // Drag has entered view bounds
        // If called for trash can then scale it.
        if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
            view.animate().scaleX(1.5f);
            view.animate().scaleY(1.5f);
        }
        return true;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        // Drag exited view bounds
        // If called for trash can then reset it.
        if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
            view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
            view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
        }
        view.invalidate();
        return true;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
        // Ignore this event
        return true;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        // Dropped inside view bounds
        // If called for trash can then delete the item and reload the grid
        // view
        if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
            drawables.remove(draggedIndex);
            draggedIndex = -1;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        // Hide the trash can
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                findViewById(R.id.trash_can).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 1000l);
        if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
            view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
            view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
        } else {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        // remove drag listeners
        view.setOnDragListener(null);
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}*/



}
```

This issue is that the onCreate() method of my gridView is never called and therefore, my gridView doesn't show up at all. I can't figure out why. All my coding in my Manifest is correct (as far as I can tell), and I have tried doing different heights and widths on my xml file to make my gridView appear. No matter what I've tried, my gridView won't show up.

Here is my Manifest by the way:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<receiver android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:resource="@xml/widget_stuff"/>

</receiver>

<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.WidgetConfig" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>

</intent-filter> 

</activity>   

<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.Drag_and_Drop_App" android:label="@string/app_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AppInfoAdapter" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.Feedback" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.SendMessageActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.Utilities" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.Personalize" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.GridView" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.SwipeDetector"  android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Please help! What could be the issue?

ADDED AFTER EDITING:

Here is my updated classes so that my adapter is in its own class...
GridView.java:

```
  package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class GridView extends Activity {// implements OnItemLongClickListener, OnDragListener{

private int draggedIndex = -1;
private BaseAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop_app);
    Log.d("GridView", "onCreate called");
    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern1);
    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern2);

    android.widget.GridView gridView = (android.widget.GridView) findViewById(R.id.GRIDVIEW1);

    // Instance of Adapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(this));
   // gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
}

/*  @Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> gridView, View view,
        int position, long row) {
    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((String) view.getTag());
    ClipData clipData = new ClipData((CharSequence) view.getTag(),
            new String[] { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN }, item);
    view.startDrag(clipData, new View.DragShadowBuilder(view), null, 0);
    View trashCan = findViewById(R.id.trash_can);
    trashCan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    trashCan.setOnDragListener(GridView.this);
    trashCan.setOnDragListener(GridView.this);
    draggedIndex = position;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
    switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // Drag has started
        // If called for trash resize the view and return true
        if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
            view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
            view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
            return true;
        } else // else check the mime type and set the view visibility
        if (dragEvent.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(
                ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        // Drag has entered view bounds
        // If called for trash can then scale it.
        if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
            view.animate().scaleX(1.5f);
            view.animate().scaleY(1.5f);
        }
        return true;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        // Drag exited view bounds
        // If called for trash can then reset it.
        if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
            view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
            view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
        }
        view.invalidate();
        return true;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
        // Ignore this event
        return true;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        // Dropped inside view bounds
        // If called for trash can then delete the item and reload the grid
        // view
        if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
            drawables.remove(draggedIndex);
            draggedIndex = -1;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        // Hide the trash can
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                findViewById(R.id.trash_can).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 1000l);
        if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
            view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
            view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
        } else {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        // remove drag listeners
        view.setOnDragListener(null);
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
*/

}
```

GridViewAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array list
public ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Constructor
public GridViewAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
// How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter
public int getCount() {
    return drawables.size();
}

@Override
// Get the data item associated with the specified position in the
// data set
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return drawables.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(mContext);
    }
    /*Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
      Bitmap default_b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
      view.setImageBitmap(default_b);*/
    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}

}
```

And then I also added this activity to my Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.GridView" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
```

*Note that I do not have GridViewAdapter as an activity in my Manifest*

Comment: Why are you making a view to extend an activity?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly, you're creating a separate Activity as a 'container' for your adapter. This is not good. Just make the Adapter itself into a separate class. Not every class in Android has to be an Activity!

Comment: So in other words, I would just remove it as an activity and just have it be the seperate class all on it's own? (Sorry if I'm misunderstanding)

Comment: Correct. Another possibility is to make it an inner class of the activity. That's usually more tidy if it's only used in that activity.

Comment: Ok so when you mean to remove it as an activity, what do I do? Sorry but in my mind that leaves either removing it from my Manifest as an activity (which I just tried and it didn't work) or removing the "extends Activity" section in my coding?

Comment: Or are you saying to take out my Base Adapter and put that into it's own activity and then to call on it from my GridView class?

Comment: Ok so I changed my coding to have the adapter in its own seperate class...but I still the the same problem of the onCreate() not being called. Please check my updated coding above!

Comment: @user2909006 i think u are not specifying which view u need to inflate in Gridview.. It should be either defined in Gridapater or else you need to use some standard grid row which is provided by framework